# Django DRF: POST to CreateAPIView with list of PrimaryKeyRelatedFields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a many-to-one relationship between the following models

```
class Story(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)


class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.URLField()

    story = models.ForeignKey(to=Story, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Suppose I post several article objects to the database successfully.
I identify that the articles with the ids

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

are all reporting on a particular Story.

I want create a Story via a POST method to a CreateAPIView view like this

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/news/story {articles': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Here is my serializer

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
     articles = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, allow_empty=False, queryset=Article.objects.all())

     class Meta:
         model = Story
         fields = ('id', 'articles')
```

Here is my view

```
class StoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = StorySerializer
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
```

I want to ensure that 1) the articles exist. 2) the article story is updated before the Story object is created.

Suppose I run this as it is, I will get the following error:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `Story.objects.create()`. This may be
>   because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not
>   a valid argument to `Story.objects.create()`. You may need to make the
>   field read-only, or override the StorySerializer.create() method to
>   handle this correctly.

So here is an attempt to override the create() method:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):

        story_id = None

        for article_id in validated_data['articles']:
            article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
            story_id = article.story_id
            if story_id:
                break

        story = Story.objects.get(id=story_id) if story_id else Story.objects.create()

        for article_id in validated_data['articles']:
            article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
            article.story_id = story.id
            article.save()

        story.save()
        return story

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return self.create(validated_data)
```

The idea here is make sure there are no overlapping stories by merging them.

When I try POST to this view, I encounter a `DoesNotExist` thrown by the line `Article.objects.get(id=article_id)`

My questions are

1) *Minor* : Why am I getting this error

2) *Major* : Is there a cleaner / correct way of addressing such a use case in django?

Thank you

Comment: You want to first create a story, then set this saved story for some articles?

Comment: Almost. If a story already exists as a foreign key of one of the articles, I want to use that and set it to the rest of the articles.

Answer (score 0):

```
class StoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = StorySerializer
    query_set = Story.objects.all()
```

It's should be `quertset` not `query_set`.

1) Minor : Why am I getting this error

You gived an illegal article_id which is not exist.

2) Major : Is there a cleaner / correct way of addressing such a use case in django?

[drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) can handle nested write in drf well.